# Interaction.Triggers fail in MVVM listbox view

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

The xaml below works correctly when I click (MouseDown) anywhere on the background of the listbox. The problem is that I can not get it to work when I click on any single  item in the listbox. I've tried putting the trigger code inside the border, image or TextBlock with no success.

```
<ListBox Name="SelectL2List" ItemsSource="{Binding L2Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <si:CallDataMethod Method="HideSelectL2View" Target="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MediaItemViewModel}" >
            <Border BorderThickness="1,1,3,3" Margin="10" CornerRadius="3">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding L2Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that things are hit testing as well, you can set the `Background` of the Border to `Transparent` to ensure that.

Also the mouse events are intercepted by the `ListBoxItems`, use the [tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) versions, i.e. `PreviewMouseDown`.

Comment: H.B. - PreviewMouseDown worked, but I need SelectionChanged to fire first and then the PreviewMouseDown event -

Comment: @LoneStarr: Why don't you trigger on `IsSelected` becomming `true` then (using a `DataTrigger`)?

Comment: I ended up changing the eventname to SelectionChanged and redid some code in the VM. I then used your tunneling tip on a combobox I was struggling with - it now works as I had hoped. Thanks for spending the time to help me gain some new knowledge.